# Angular - How does a http request flow in and out of Angular 2

Tags: angular

What is the order of flow of data from a request from a service to the API server

Does request go via HTTPCLIENT -> INTERCEPTOR -> API

and response via API -> INTERCEPTOR -> HTTPCLIENT

I have a HTTP API call from my application, initiated from a component via a service. The service uses http client to call the api and get the response. I have also created a HTTP interceptor to intercept these requests and responses.

I was expecting to intercept a header from the server via INTERCEPTOR but it turns out the header was available in the HTTPCLIENT's observable only. Please correct me if I am wrong about the request response flow

Answer (score 2):

You are right. HTTP request goes like HTTPCLIENT -> INTERCEPTOR -> API and response will be get as API -> INTERCEPTOR -> HTTPCLIENT.
For more information please visit [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses).